# Enabling speaker doesn't work

Tags: sinch

so far, I have been able to enable the speaker while using Sinch. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. I have had this issue on both an iPhone 5S and iPhone 6.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
- (void)speaker {
    id <SINAudioController> audio = [self.sinchClient audioController];
    [audio enableSpeaker];
}
```

And here is where it is being called from:

```
- (void)callDidEstablish:(id<SINCall>)call;
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Call did establish");

    // Set speaker and mute
    [self mute];
    [self speaker];
}
```

Comment: Yes that looks just about right, are you doing it after a call is established?

Comment: I updated my question showing where it is being called from @cjensen

Comment: Even stranger, it seems to work occasionally, but not often. If I do a ton of calls on maybe one of them the speaker works. The call if frequently muted and un muted. Would this possibly cause the problems with the speaker? (Sorry if I'm repeating myself from my email)

Comment: I will report this to the SDK product team so they can try and reproduce it. Thank you so much for you feedbak